# Put html tag inside <option> generated from f.input (simple form or rails forms)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form

I'm generating form with `simple_form_for` helper.
I've got input like this.

`= f.input :color, label: "color", collection: input_collection, include_blank: false`

here is response from `input_collection`:
```

````
[["<span>test</span>black", "black"],
 ["<span>test</span>silver", "silver"],
 ["<span>test</span>gray", "gray"],
 ["<span>test</span>maroon", "maroon"],
 ["<span>test</span>red", "red"],
 ["<span>test</span>purple", "purple"],
 ["<span>test</span>fuchsia", "fuchsia"],
 ["<span>test</span>green", "green"],
 ["<span>test</span>lime", "lime"],
 ["<span>test</span>olive", "olive"],
 ["<span>test</span>yellow", "yellow"],
 ["<span>test</span>navy", "navy"],
 ["<span>test</span>blue", "blue"],
 ["<span>test</span>teal", "teal"],
 ["<span>test</span>aqua", "aqua"]]
```
````

and unfortunately it renders to this: 
[image]

The question is: how to make these s render as html tags (so I can give them styles!)
Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried calling `.html_safe` on the strings as you add them to the array? (Obviously being careful that there's no way they could have come from an unsafe source...)

Comment: tried `.html_safe`. It completely removes <span> from option

Comment: @AFaderDarkly have a look on this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25199135/add-span-inside-option-tag-and-style-it

Comment: Interesting. Time to get out the ol' Javascript then. (With a less styled no-js fall-back of course...)

Comment: try `input_collection.join.html_safe`. iirc correctly, if choices is a string, then the select tag will use this string as the html.