# Add span inside <option> tag and style it

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome

I would like to add span before text inside `<option>` tag and style it (it should represent color in select menu). However it does't seem to work...

How to make this piece of code working?

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bartuz/08e0L9j2/2/

It seems example above does work in Firefox only... what about other browsers?

Comment: Even though this is not allowed, I can see some colored boxes in my Firefox 30.0 - so what exactly is not working?!

Comment: In chrome in doesn't...

Comment: The fiddle linked works exactly as you say you describe -- there's a colored box, then the text. It's not valid HTML though, so it may not be consistent across browsers

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/kheema/08e0L9j2/3/ is this what you want?

Comment: it doesn't work in chrome @KheemaPandey

Comment: yes just realized that. As per specification made by w3c `option` element cannot get styled. And in this case IE implemented it correctly.

Comment: HTML5 supposedly adds the [`input type="color"`](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_type_color), however it is not well supported yet (see [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#search=color)). It will be a cool feature once it get support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will depend on your web browser. In the latest version of Firefox, it works fine. However, it doesn't work in the latest version of Internet Explorer.

Your question is a bit loaded - and I suspect that's why it got downvoted - you are asking why it's not working, rather than how to get it to work.

It's not working because it's not really a supported feature of selectboxes (yet!)

I'd suggest you look into using JavaScript to achieve the same result (and specifically, the [jQuery UI selectmenu](http://jqueryui.com/selectmenu/)) which should support this type of 'advanced' select box.

Comment: It shouldn't work in Firefox at all as the `option` element is not allowed to contain HTML descendants.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly Why not? The specification specifies what's valid HTML, and how valid HTML must render. Handling invalid html, afaik, is implementation-specific

Comment: @blgt In this case Firefox is clearly *not* handling the invalid HTML properly.  Passing this through W3's validator will give two errors: *Stray start tag `span`.* and *Stray end tag `span`.*, confirming that this HTML is invalid. Firefox should be completely removing any HTML elements from within the `option` and only displaying plain text.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly [This page](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/appendix/notes.html#h-B.1) says it "does *not* define" what should happen

Comment: James Donnelly, blgt is correct in that the web browser should not remove invalid markup. A lot of the web is actually marked up incorrectly and doing this would break many sites. The web browser should undertake the best endeavour to make what the developer wants to happen actually happen. It is up to the web browser to decide exactly how it does that, and that's why you get such a large difference between how the different browsers do things.

Comment: @AlastairCampbell the "best endeavour" in this situation would be to strip the HTML tags and only output plain text as it seems all other browsers apart from Firefox currently do. `<option><span>Hello, world!</span></option>` should realistically only be rendered as `<option>Hello, world!</option>`. In my mind this should be raised as a bug on Firefox's bug tracker.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't rely on the fact that your hack works on Firefox, does not mean it should on Chrome too.

Anyway, styling selects was always frustrating and there's no easy way to customize native select elements.

If you're looking for a way to style the native select elements, maybe this will help:

https://catalin.red/making-html-dropdowns-not-suck/

Answer (score 0):

An option element isn't allowed to have child elements.
I've extended  your same answer, but instead applied the background color to the option element as demonstrated in this jsfiddle link: 
https://jsfiddle.net/go4zee/6L0jjjoa/

```
$('#tag_item_color option').each(function () {
    var color = $(this).text();
    console.log(color);
    $(this).closest("option").css({"background-color":color});

})
```